# How do you make post request in vue using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, axios

I'm using Vue, with springboot, on two different localhosts, and I can get information with axios, but how do I make a request for adding a new object to the api. I googled for some answers but nothing seems to help me, or maybe I am doing this the wrong way.

Here is how I get api in the first place. How do I make a post request?

```
import axios from "axios";
```

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/items")
      // .get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then((response) => (this.info = response.data._embedded.items));
  },
};
```

Comment: Your API needs to have an endpoint that accepts a POST request, then you would need to use `axios.post` in the front end.

Comment: @MattU I have "filter" on the backend which lets only my other localhost access the data, also that HttpServletResponse has set ```  httpresponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"); ``` do I access the POST method as axios.post("http://localhost:8080/items) then? And if so, how would whole  code line look like?

Comment: If you're not sure how to create an API endpoint that accepts a POST in spring boot then I recommend researching that. Find a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, vue and spingboot are decoupled, meaning that if you have an endpoint on your springboot backend that accepts POST requests, you are good to go.
An example of POST request with axios would be

```
   axios({urlPath: 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json', data: correctFormatedDataThatTheApiAccepts, method: 'POST', headers: headersThatYouNeed})
```

the above request returns a Promise and that's the way you should handle it.

Comment: Syntax like that did not work out for me, but the correctFormatedData helped a lot, thanks